# LibGDX's Box2D having weird rotation behavior when setting angular velocity

Tags: java, libgdx, game-physics, box2d

I created a simple dynamic body from a PolygonShape and rendering it as a PolygonSprite rendered by a PolygonSpriteBatch. The rendering works fine, but the physics is not. The translation due to velocity works well, but when I set angular velocity or apply torque the body "orbits" around a point while rotating on its origin too. The problem isn't the origin, as while debugging I noticed that the body's position is also changing. The only rotation shouldn't make the body translate, right?

Here's how it rotates. I've only set angular velocity.

[image: rotation behavior]

The linear velocity is always equal to 0 as I checked during debugging, but the position changes (which doesn't make any sense), so it should not be a rendering problem caused by a wrong rotation origin.

Here's where I create the body with the polygon.

```
public DrawableBody createFullBody(float[] vertices, Body body, Texture tex, Vector2 coord){
    //in our example: vertices = new float[]{0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1f, 1f, 1f, 1f, 0.0f};
    DrawableBody out = new DrawableBody(); //a class that contains Body and PolygonSprite
    ShortArray indices = triangulate(vertices); //uses EarClippingTriangulator
    
    PolygonShape shape = new PolygonShape();
    shape.set(vertices);

    FixtureDef fixtureDef = new FixtureDef();
    fixtureDef.shape = shape;
    fixtureDef.density = 1f;
    fixtureDef.restitution = 0.9f;
    
    Fixture fixture = body.createFixture(fixtureDef);
    
    shape.dispose(); //this is useless now, so we can dispose it.
    
    PolygonRegion region = new PolygonRegion(new TextureRegion(tex), vertices, indices.toArray());
    PolygonSprite sprite = new PolygonSprite(region);
    body.setTransform(coord, 0);
    sprite.setPosition(coord.x, coord.y);
    
    out.body = body;
    out.poly = sprite;
    
    return out;
}
```

And that's how I render the square:

```
public void render(PolygonSpriteBatch batch, float delta){
    Vector2 pos = body.getPosition(); //this changes even if velocity is zero?!?
    Vector2 size = model.robotSize; //this is Vector2(0.1f, 0.1f)
    
    float angle = body.getAngle();
    
    d_body.poly.setPosition(pos.x - size.x / 2.0f, pos.y - size.y / 2.0f);
    d_body.poly.setSize(size.x, size.y);
    d_body.poly.setOrigin(size.x / 2.0f, size.y / 2.0f);
    d_body.poly.setRotation(angle);
    
    batch.draw(d_body.poly.getRegion(), 
            d_body.poly.getX(),       d_body.poly.getY(),
            d_body.poly.getOriginX(), d_body.poly.getOriginY(), 
            d_body.poly.getWidth(),   d_body.poly.getHeight(), 
            1.0f, 1.0f,
            d_body.poly.getRotation());
}
```

I'm struggling with this issue for two days now, so any help would really be appreciated.

Comment: What does it look like if you render it with the Box2DDebugRenderer?

Comment: @bornander I managed to solve the problem. Basically it was a wrong transformation of coordinates between box2d and the graphics. The coordinates system of box2d was 10 times bigger than the graphics one, and I had to scale it.